# How can one incorporate spatial correlations into time series forecasting?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, graph-neural-networks, forecasting

I am working on a project, where I am trying to predict temperatures of various streets and I have their locations recorded.
I was wondering if I could somehow train a model that could incorporate their relative positions and somehow account for it during the temperature predictions.
I plan on using a temporal fusion transformer as there will be several variables and I will want to predict multi-step horizons.
Does anyone have an idea how this could be achieved? I was thinking maybe graph neural networks, but I'm not sure where exactly they would be incorporated.